# AC capacitor current spike

Tags: capacitor, current, ac

I was experimenting with capacitor voltage divider circuits but something unusual happened. Circuit is really simple , I connected 100uF 16v capacitor into 13.85V 50hz AC supply Xc is 26.5 ohm So I expected current will be 0.5A but multimeter showed 1A-1.2A then capacitor exploded.

I assumed capacitor overheated and that caused the explosion but why current is twice than it supposed to be ?

I made similar circuits with 47uF and 1uF capacitors and everything was right , why 100uF acts differently ?

Capacitors are radial electrolytic

Comment: How did you connect it? If you had some inductance in the connection, it would reduce the total reactance and increase the current delivered.

Comment: Only one capacitor nothing else .capacitor's positive side connected to supply other side connected to multimeter's positive probe and multimeter's negative probe connected to supply

Comment: What was the supply? a transformer connected to mains?

Comment: Yeah I just thought same thing too , I didn't realize supply is step down transformer so it have inductance too . Thanks

Comment: I checked inductance of transformer and it has 9mH inductance so reactance is 3.2 ohm . Transformer's max current rating is 1.5 A so it act like short circuit ?Also transformer connected parallel or series ?

Comment: its AC; that large cap may only tolerate one-polarity of use.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're saying , can you explain it a little ?

Comment: What @analogsystemsrf wrote applies to all capacitors, because OP wrote:  *Capacitors are radial electrolytic*

Comment: I'm supposed to use non electrolytic ceramic capacitor ? Their capacity is lot less than electrolytic ones

Comment: "Standard electrolytic capacitors, and aluminum as well as tantalum and niobium electrolytic capacitors are polarized and generally require the anode electrode voltage to be positive relative to the cathode voltage." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolytic_capacitor Your AC signal will violate this requirement half the time. It really seems as if your 47µF and 1µF capacitors should have exploded also.

Comment: Why ? I used the polarized capacitor reverse before they never exploded they just don't charge . Also I think I found why the capacitor exploded not because of transformer or negative polarity . Capacitor rated for 16v but transformer supplies -14 to 14v so peak voltage is 28V so capacitor couldn't hold the voltage and became a conductive also this the same reason why 1uF and 47uF didn't explode because they rated for 50V . I changed 100uf capacitor into 400V 100uf one and circuit worked just fine

Comment: @Mordecai No, it isn't the peak-to-peak voltage that is causing your problem. The capacitor only sees half that, the peak, on each half cycle because the other end can be thought of as being connected to the middle (0V) of the signal. However 13.85V RMS has a peak voltage of 19.6V which exceeds the 16V rating. In any case, as several people have pointed out, an electrolytic capacitor is not designed to be reverse biassed and I guess that you were just lucky that the other capacitors you tried didn't also explode.